# In SQLAlchemy can `backref` param inside a `relationship` be assigned a variable?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using joind table inheritance here.

```
class BaseEntity(Base):
    some_col = Column(String)
    base_relationship = relationship("some_relationship", backref="depends_on_who_inherits_me")

class SubEntity(BaseEntity):
    some_unique_col = Column(String)
```

Because the specific backref name will only become known in the run-time(in this case, it should be `SubEntity`, but it should be able to be inheritable by unlimited subclasses), I need `depends_on_who_inherits_me` part a variable, or more specifically, the inheriting sub-class's name, instead of a string. So each sub-class will have a relationship referring to a third-party class, while having it referring back to that particular sub-class by its appropriate name.

However, because this is outside of any method, I can't use `self` to flexibly refer to the instances.

How to implement this idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you might achieve this is with a [`Mixin`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html) that uses [`declared_attr.cascading`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr.cascading).

Here's the mixin class:

```py
class Mixin:

    @declared_attr.cascading
    def related_entity(cls):
        if has_inherited_table(cls):
            return relationship(
                'RelatedEntity',
                backref=cls.__name__.lower(),
                uselist=False
            )
```

The `cascading` flag on `declared_attr` will make sqlalchemy attempt to render the 'mixed in' attribute on every class in the hierarchy. Or as the docs put it:

> This is a special-use modifier which indicates that a column or
>   MapperProperty-based declared attribute should be configured
>   distinctly per mapped subclass, within a mapped-inheritance scenario.

The [`has_inherited_table()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.has_inherited_table) function, allows us to determine within the mixin if we are dealing with the `BaseEntity` or a subclass, so that we only add the relationships on to the subclasses.

The mixin is then inherited into the `BaseEntity` model:

```py
class BaseEntity(Base, Mixin):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    related_id = sa.Column(
        sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('relatedentity.id'))
    discriminator = sa.Column(sa.String)

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        if has_inherited_table(cls):
            args = {'polymorphic_identity': cls.__name__.lower()}
        else:
            args = {'polymorphic_on': cls.discriminator}
        return args
```

As you mentioned in your question that you are using joined table inheritance, I've defined the `__mapper_args__` on `BaseEntity` using a `@declared_attr` method so that the `polymorphic_identity` also can be automatically generated from the class name for  the subclasses.

So with this configuration, every subclass of `BaseEntity` will apply a relationship attribute on `RelatedEntity` named after the subclass. Here's the full working example:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import (declarative_base, declared_attr,
                                        has_inherited_table)
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker


class BaseClass:

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()


Base = declarative_base(cls=BaseClass)
engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class Mixin:

    @declared_attr.cascading
    def related_entity(cls):
        if has_inherited_table(cls):
            return relationship(
                'RelatedEntity',
                backref=cls.__name__.lower(),
                uselist=False
            )


class BaseEntity(Base, Mixin):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    related_id = sa.Column(
        sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('relatedentity.id'))
    discriminator = sa.Column(sa.String)

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        if has_inherited_table(cls):
            args = {'polymorphic_identity': cls.__name__.lower()}
        else:
            args = {'polymorphic_on': cls.discriminator}
        return args


class RelatedEntity(Base):
    """ Class that is related to all `BaseEntity` subclasses"""
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)


class SubEntity(BaseEntity):
    """ Will generate `RelatedEntity.subentity`"""
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('baseentity.id'),
                   primary_key=True)


class OtherEntity(BaseEntity):
    """ Will generate `RelatedEntity.otherentity`"""
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('baseentity.id'),
                   primary_key=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    s = Session()
    rel_inst = RelatedEntity()
    s.add(rel_inst)
    rel_inst.subentity.append(SubEntity())
    rel_inst.otherentity.append(OtherEntity())
    s.commit()
    print(rel_inst.subentity, rel_inst.otherentity)
    # [<__main__.SubEntity object at 0x0000023487D42C18>] [<__main__.OtherEntity object at 0x0000023487D60278>]
```

The reason we can't define the `related_entity()` `declared_attr` method in `BaseModel` is because SQLAlchemy will not honor the cascade, and there will be no relationships generated (becuase the `if has_inherited_table(cls):` block prevents `BaseModel` from generating one). From [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr.cascading):

> The flag only applies to the use of declared_attr on declarative mixin
>   classes and `__abstract__` classes; it currently has no effect when used
>   on a mapped class directly.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. After reading the documentation on `declared_attr` I am still puzzled why you would use `.cascading` inside the `Mixin` but not in the `BaseEntity`. You mentioned that it is for producing a distinctive instance for each subclass. Should those two cases be treated equal in this sense?

Comment: I've provided an update to my answer, but in short, SQLAlchemy doesn't treat the two cases the same (i.e. `related_entity()` defined on `Mixin` and `BaseModel` do not behave the same.

Comment: Please correct me if my understanding is not correct: having `cascading` or without it only affects the third generation sub-classes and beyond, it doesn't affect the second generation? From your example the `SubEntity` can still inherit `__tablename__` without a `cascading` setting.

Comment: Also, why is having a mapped table a reliable indicator of whether it's BaseEntity or SubEntity? Could you give a little hint here? Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the difference between `__tablename__` and the `relationship` `declared_attr`, have you read this? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#mixing-in-columns-in-inheritance-scenarios.

Comment: `BaseModel` inherits from `Base`, which doesn’t have a table. Other classes in the joined table inheritance hierarchy inherit from `BaseModel` which does have a table. So it’s a simple way to know if we are operating on `BaseModel` or a subclass.

Comment: Thank you very much! I promise one last question: inside your `__mapper_args__` conditional there is no `polymorphic_identity` for the `BaseEntity`, but I read the documentation and the example there seems one. Was that an overlook or there is some reason for it?

Comment: That just depends on your model. If it makes sense to have objects that are `BaseEntity` instances, then it will need it's own identity too. You can just add that in.